# No muestra nada el mulador de Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, programación-móvil

estoy comenzando con Android Studio, al lanzar el emulador no muestra nada, aparece el móvil en negro, luego muestra un mensaje que todo fue bien, ¿me falta algo por hacer?, ¿alguna configuración más?, ¿alguna idea?. Un saludo y gracias....

Comment: Tienes algún label o no tiene nada tu aplicación?

Comment: Buenas tardes, tengo una caja de texto y un botón.

Comment: Que layout estás usando ? Nunca he visto un mensaje que indique "todo fue bien", especifica exactamente que es lo que se muestra. Podrías agregar más información por favor?, Revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Mejor si adjuntas unas imágenes para ver que tal y tu código